# Get type from class in template

Tags: c++, templates

Sorry this is a lengthy question, but this is a specific problem.

Let's say I have two classes, `type1` and `type2`:

```
struct type1 {
    int getVal() {
        return int();
    }
};
struct type2 {
    float getVal() {
        return float();
    }
};
```

As you can see, they perform identical functions, except for the type returned by `getVal()`. Now, lets say I want to make a function that accepts either a `type1` or a `type2` as an input, and outputs an `std::vector` of their respective types, `int` and `float`.

The way I thought to do it was to create a template function like this:

```
template<class T> vector<oh dear> something(T input) {
    return {input.getVal(),input.getVal()};
}
```

This almost works, but as you can see from the `oh dear`, I can't create the correct type of vector to return. So I thought of a solution to that: simply typedef the type returned in the `type1` and `type2` classes, like such:

```
struct type1 {
    int getVal() {
        return int();
    }
    typedef int subtype;
};
struct type2 {
    float getVal() {
        return float();
    }
    typedef float subtype;
};
```

And change the function to this:

```
template<class T> vector<T::subtype> something(T input) {
    return {input.getVal(),input.getVal()};
}
```

Which doesn't compile. Is there any way to solve the problem I am having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `typename` keyword before `T::subtype` to tell compiler it is a type

```
template<class T> 
std::vector<typename T::subtype> something(T input) {
    return {input.getVal(),input.getVal()};
}
```

[In Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76396f4f59e1bd7a)

With C++11, you can let compiler figure out the type automatically

```
template<class T> 
auto something(T input) -> std::vector<decltype(input.getVal())>  {
    return {input.getVal(),input.getVal()};
}
```

[In Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6538361437bf460)

Comment: So THAT'S what the `typename` keyword is for! And that's what `decltype` is for! I love you, never knew auto could be a return type. I ♥ C++11 so much, thank you! Best answer ever.